# Is there any way to specify the type in Typescript of an object where the leaves are all one type but the key names are flexible?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Couldn't think of an easy way to phrase the title, an example should be clearer:

Say I have an interface:

```
interface Vehicle {
  color: string;
  year: number;
}
```

Now I have two objects:

```
const FIRST = {
  cars: {
    a: {color: "red", year: "1980"},
    b: {color: "blue", year: "1991"}
  },
  trucks: {
    red_trucks: {
      c: {color: "red", year: "1990"}
    }
  }
}

const SECOND = {
  collection: {
    new_cars: {
      x: {color: "green", year: "2015"},
      y: {color: "blue", year: "2019"}
    }
  }
}
```

The names and structure of the keys in the objects are different - `FIRST` has `cars->a, b` and `trucks->red_trucks- c` while `SECOND` just has `collection->new_cars->x, y`. And let's say there will be many objects like this, all with different key names.

But they're kind of similar, still, in that really the object is just storing `Vehicle`s, but it happens to nest some objects to do that.

Is there any way to specify a type here that would be something like "We don't know the keys but each key's value is either another object with more keys or a `Vehicle`"? Some kind of recursive type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type that describes this is actually a fairly simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Tree<T> = {
  [key: string]: T | Tree<T> | undefined
}
```

I've written this as a generic, but the `T` in your case would be `Vehicle`.  For every property of the `Tree` object, we say that the value is either a `Vehicle`, another `Tree<Vehicle>`, or `undefined`.  I am including that `undefined` because at run-time you'll want to assume that not every property is defined.  You should check that you actually have a value.

Both of your examples are assignable to `Tree<Vehicle>`.  Check it out in the [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQA37w).

Answer (score -1):

Can you? Yes. Should you? No. You are basically asking can you disable types.

If you can't describe the type, you can't interact with it safely. And typescript will only get in your way. "Some level of nesting" is so ambiguous you would never get any value in typescript.

Either: more strongly define your conceptual types
Or: skip using types all together using Record<string, any> to cheese out of using typescript